# URL content dimensions

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way, in ASP.NET (in code behind), to get page dimensions (width and height) using just the URL. Maybe download the URL content and then get width and height?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by width and height? Surely that depends on the browser that the user makes the request with?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by `using just the URL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET code behind, you cannot get the client height/width..and it shouldn't be relevant server side to speak ideally..